# how to go on next page from cell tableView to 2 page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I create one page with name ViewControll that is tableview.
I read 2 group NSString from url and store that in NSMutableArray. (names : file & folder) and both array store one array with name:(all) this NSMutableArray display in root page (ViewController)

I have two page another with names: (TabelViewController & DetailViewController) that TabelViewController is for folder array and DetailViewController is for file array.

I want when to click on cell if that cell is from folder array go on to TableViewController page else if that cell is from file array go on to DetailViewController page.

this is my code but dont work!!!:
**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *folder;
    NSMutableArray *file;
    NSMutableArray *all;
    NSInteger folderNumber,fileNumber;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tables;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *Number1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.101/mamal/filemanager.php?dir=root&filenum"]];
     fileNumber = [Number1 integerValue];

    NSString *Number2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.101/mamal/filemanager.php?dir=root&foldernum"]];
     folderNumber = [Number2 integerValue];

    NSLog(@"file: %d & folder: %d",fileNumber,folderNumber);

    for (int i=0; i < folderNumber; i++)
    {
        NSString *folderName = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.101/mamal/filemanager.php?dir=root&folder=%d&name",i]]];
        if (!folder)
        {
            folder = [NSMutableArray array];
        }
        [folder addObject:folderName];
    }

    for (int j=0; j < fileNumber; j++)
    {
        NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.101/mamal/filemanager.php?dir=root&file=%d&name",j]]];
        NSLog(@"%@",fileName);
        if (!file)
        {
            file = [NSMutableArray array];
        }
        [file addObject:fileName];
    } 
    all = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [all addObjectsFromArray:folder];
    [all addObjectsFromArray:file];    
}
#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return all.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [all objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row+1);

    if (indexPath.row+1 <= folderNumber)
        {

            TableViewController *tab = [[TableViewController alloc]init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:tab animated:YES];
        }
    else
    {
        if (indexPath.row+1 > folderNumber)
        {
            DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`-initWithNibName:bundle:` is the designated initializer for UIViewController.

```
TableViewController *vc = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Use this kind of initialization for the view controllers

Answer (score 1):

try this

search the selected name in the individual array of folder and files

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
  if([folder containsObject:[all objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])
    {
       TableViewController *tableVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableViewController"]; 
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableVC animated:YES]; 
    }
  else
    {
       DetailViewController *detail = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: because the DetailViewController is blank mostProbably use [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil]; i have edited the answere

Comment: please tell me more about this . I so confused

Comment: then use [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Table" sender: self]; instead of pushViewController

Comment: try this UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil]; 
TableViewController *tableVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tableVC animated:YES];

Comment: can you give me the crashLog

Comment: glad i could help, please accept the answer for future reference of other users.